# Unbanning a specific user

Tags: discord, discord.py

Important note: I'm not using the rewrite.

I've been trying to unban specific users on a message in discord.py with a command.
Example:

On the command "!unban," the bot unbans a user who was not mentioned in the command.

I've tried something like

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message): 
 if message.content == x:
  await message.guild.unban('[User ID], *, reason=none')
```

which results in

```
await self._state.http.unban(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

If anybody could help me out, I'd appreciate it. I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper usage of that command is `guild.unban(user, reason=None)`. The asterisk is not required in a call to the function, and `=None` indicates that reason is optional. If you do not have a reason:

In your case:

```
await message.guild.unban(userID)
```

Should do the job, so long as your user ID is in the format of a [snowflake](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Snowflake) object (e.g. a `User` object for that user!)

Comment: Tysm. I feel pretty stupid now tbh, but I'm glad you helped out